# Is it possible (with an MSI using WiX) to advertise shortcuts to "all users", but to do the actual installation "per user"?

Tags: wix

My MSI installer is authored using WiX.

It installs "per user", in order to allow non-administrator users to install updates (`InstallScope` attribute of `Package` element is set to `perUser`).

However, I'd like be able to "[advertise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367548%28VS.85%29.aspx)" the application to "all users". Ideally, when the user clicks the link, the installation launches in a "per user" context, with their own privileges (i.e. not elevated).

**Can I do this with WiX, and how?**

Comment: Even if it may be possible, the installer may demand for that to be run Administrator mode I think.

Comment: In hindsight this was a silly question. If I do anything that affects all users, I must install as Administrator.